# How can I use htop or top to monitor CPUs' usage and output the infomation to a file?

Tags: top, htop

I want to monitor the CPUs' usage when a program is running. I came out with the idea, that htop has the CPU usage information on the top. I wonder if I can somehow run htop, make it refresh every 0.1 second, and output the information about CPU usage to a file. Does anyone have an idea how to achieve that? Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: That's what tools like `sar`, `atop`, or `below` are for -- don't reinvent the wheel by trying to parse something which was never designed to be parsed.

Comment: @ChrisDown Great, sar is exactly what I should actually use, thanks a lot!

Comment: Using `top -b` (batch mode) outputs plain text (no colours or ncurses escapes), which is reasonably easy to parse.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using sar command and wrote a short script so that it keeps running until ctrl+c stops it.

Comment: Doesn't, for instance, `sar 1` already keep it running with a 1 sec interval until you hit ^c? What more do you need in a script?

Comment: oh, that is even better, thnaks.